# How to disable vertical center when centered element's height is longer than window height? (without Javascript)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to make site content vertically centered with `display: flex; align-items: center;` on normal mode. But if content changes and centered element height goes longer than window, it should behave like normal as `align-items: flex-start;`.

Use-case is that and I will share a sample fiddle belove with you.

Actual problem is that I should **not use javascript** on this issue, it should be solved by pure CSS code. (I added javascript to just show you how to increase content and see problem.)
If you try to click button on fiddle it will demonstrate my issue click more and see overflow is not run well and you can not see top elements. I need a clever option to make run this, thank you for helping.

html:

```
<div id="box">
    <div>
      <button id='click'>
        click me
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
html,body{
  min-height:100%;
  height:100%
}
#box {
   height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#box div {
  background:tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var para = document.createElement("P");    
    para.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";  
    document.getElementById("box").children[0].appendChild(para);

});
```

let me show real-life sample images and then share fiddle to make it more cleaner.

normal mode:[image]

long content mode: [image]

jsfiddle:
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/ariciaykut/3awkj5nb/21/)

as it is shown on this image overflow is not true also, it shows top but it is not top of the window.

Comment: CSS can't detect overflow. You *will* need javascript I suspect.

Comment: Well I am not sure but may be some of your problem will be solve using `height media quires` like `@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {...}` but for complete solution you need `JS`

Comment: thank you I tried media max-height before, but it ll be dynamic content and without checking content height, max-height could not solve my issue.  I need to solve this without JS because at the end of the day this will turn to a CSS library for next projects.

Comment: Is it something to do with responsive layout our you would like your div to cover window and have something in the center?

Comment: @Agil if content is smaller than the window it should be vertically centered box, else it should be flex-start from top of the window.

Comment: As stated **you can't do this with CSS**, you need to re-think your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @Paulie_D so if I can not get any another idea I won't use flex-center. And I shared a javascript solution for other people who may have same issue and can use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for your requirements, but you need to start by changing the direction of the flexbox (you are using the default `flex-direction: row` but you'll need to switch to `flex-direction: column`). This will allow you to really take advantage of the dynamic sizing nature of flexboxes in the way that you need.

Since you are switching the orientation of the flexbox, you'll also need to switch your `align-items` and `justify-content` values. Since the effect you want is to end up with is `justify-content: flex-start`, go ahead and switch that now. You'll simulated `justify-content: center` with some placeholder elements.

Once you are using the flexbox vertically, you can then put in some placeholders that will shrink as the actual content grows. Put an empty div with this placeholder class above an below the actual content. The placeholder class then needs to be styled so that it can only shrink using `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-shrink: 1` (this works best if all other elements have `flex-shrink: 0`). It will also need to be styled with an initial height (I used `height: 50vh` but that might vary based on your needs).

With the flex-direction switched and the placeholders added, the last thing you need to do is set a height or max-height on the flexbox so that the placeholders will actually shrink. I recommend using `height: 100vh` but you can use something different based on the needs of your project.

Here's the end result (based on your sample code). I've made a few other tweaks (like setting the background on the placeholder) that are pretty specific to the example code and likely not what you need for your actual solution. I also eliminated some unnecessary code (like the styling on the HTML and body).

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {

  var para = document.createElement("P");
  para.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
  document.getElementById("box").children[1].appendChild(para);

});
```

```css
#box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

#box>* {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#box>.placeholder {
  height: 50vh;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 100;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div>
    <button id='click'>
    click me
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it's a very useful and clever idea thank you for answer. To solve this problem we need some tricky thing like that. Just we don't need `overflow: auto;` on `#box` to prevent double scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with javascript but I should not use javascript. I decided to do not use flex center on my project.

So I am sharing this javascript solution to help if someone has the same problem and can use javascript on his project.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(){

    var para = document.createElement("P");    
    para.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";  
    document.getElementById("box").children[0].appendChild(para);

  var el=document.getElementById("box");
  if(el.children[0].offsetHeight>document.body.offsetHeight){
    el.style.height='auto';
  }else{
    el.style.height='100%';
  }

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ariciaykut/1mrLhjv7/1/)